# JS for-loop how to get the first value

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm sorry for the dumb question. I've been trying to do this for hours now, and i really can't get it to work. So i have a for-loop that loops though some numbers.
But it doesn't take the first value(`71990000`).

How can this be achieved?
This is what i've got so far:

```
        var minNr = 0000;
        var maxNr = 10000;
        var prefix = 7199;

        function Nummer(min,max)
        {
            var regex = /^(\d{2})\1$/;

            var guld_nr;
            for(guld_nr = minNr; guld_nr < maxNr;)
            {
                if(regex.test(guld_nr))
                {
                    $(".resultat").append(prefix + "" + guld_nr + "<br>");
                }

                guld_nr++;
            }

        }
```

The output is this:

```
71991010
71991111
71991212
71991313
```

But i also need the number: `71990000`
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your regex is rejecting the number 0; the first time through the loop, `minNr` has the numeric value 0 (setting it to 0000 doesn't help; it's just a fancy way of saying 0).  The regex expects two digits followed by the same pattern, but what you're giving it is the string '0'.

You could set `minNr` to be a string instead on the first pass through (`'0000'`), and this will solve the problem for '0000', but you will miss '0101', '0202', etc. (which will convert to the strings '101', '202', and so on.)

One solution would be to zero pad the string representation of your number.  The following function will take any number and left zero pad it to fit a given width:

```
function zeropad(n, w) {
    n = String(n);
    while(n.length < w) n = '0' + n;
    return n;
}
```

You can use it to convert `minNr` for the regex:

```
regex.test(zeropad(guld_nr, 4))
```

Also note that `Number` is a built-in object wrapper for literals in JavaScript (all of the primitives have object wrappers: `Number`, `Boolean`, `String`), and by creating a function called `Number`, you are occluding this built-in object, which is inadvisable (code that needs to use it will invoke your function instead, which is incompatible and has a different purpose).

Comment: I've just tried your solution, and it works more or less. Altho i'm getting the output: 71990, 7199101, 7199202, which means i'm missing a zero in the front of the number. Like it should be 71990101.

Comment: You need to use the `zeropad` function _wherever_ you're converting the number to the string and you need it padded with zeros.  In my answer, I tried to address the understanding of the issue; that numbers are not strings.  They can be converted to a _string representation_ which does _not normally include left-padded zeros_.

Answer (score 0):

Use string:

```
var minNr = '0000';
```

It's the start value for the regex test, and you need the four zeroes for that. If it would be a number, then you get only one zero for testing. it would help, if you pad it with leading zeroes.

```js
var minNr = '0000', 
    maxNr = 10000,
    prefix = 7199;

function Nummer(min,max)        {
    var regex = /^(\d{2})\1$/;

    var guld_nr;
    for(guld_nr = minNr; guld_nr < maxNr;guld_nr++)            {
        if(regex.test(guld_nr))                {
            document.write(prefix + "" + guld_nr + "<br>");
        }                
    }
}

Nummer(minNr, maxNr);
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the job! Can you tell me, why i needed the zero's to be a string? I would like to know, for another time

Comment: it's the start value for the regex test, and you need the four zeroes for that. if it would be a number, then you get only one zero for testing. it would help, if you pad it with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers don't zero-pad themselves; `0000; // 0`
Make a custom zero-pad method for it so you can do `zpad(0, 4); // "0000"`

```
function zpad(x, digits) {
    var pad = '0';
    x = x.toString();
    digits -= x.length;
    while (digits > 0) {
        if (digits & 1) x = pad + x;
        pad += pad;
        digits >>>= 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Now adjust `Nummer` accordingly

```
function Nummer(min, max, prefix) {
    var regex = /^(\d{2})\1$/,
        i, str;
    prefix = prefix || '';

    for(i = min; i < max; ++i) {
        str = zpad(i, 4);
        if(regex.test(str)) console.log(prefix + str);
    }
}
```

and use

```
Nummer(minNr, maxNr, '7199');
```

---

Side note

- `Nummer` is not constructing an *Object*, consider camel casing it

Answer (score 0):

You could use arithmetic to do the digit pattern check, and keep the result numerical:

```js
var minNr = 0; // it does not help to put 4 zeroes here.
var maxNr = 10000;
var prefix = 7199;

function Nummer(min,max) {
    for (var guld_nr = min; guld_nr < max; guld_nr++) {
        if (Math.floor(guld_nr/100) === guld_nr % 100 ) {
            $(".resultat").append((prefix * 10000 + guld_nr) + "<br>");
        }
    }
}

Nummer(minNr, maxNr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resultat"></div>
```

The problem with your code is when the lower numbers are tested against the regular expression, they are implicitly converted to string, and do not get prefixed zeroes, so they fail on the regular expression.

Anyway, the code will be more efficient when sticking to numbers instead of strings, so I would suggest working with numbers all the way up to the point of outputting them in the browser.

Even more efficient is this code:

```js
var minNr = 0; // it does not help to put 4 zeroes here.
var maxNr = 10000;
var prefix = 7199;

function Nummer(min,max) {
    var test = Math.floor(min/100)*100 + Math.floor(min/100)%100;
    var guld_nr = test < min ? test + 101 : test;
    for (; guld_nr < max; guld_nr+=101) {
        $(".resultat").append((prefix * 10000 + guld_nr) + "<br>");
    }
}

Nummer(minNr, maxNr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resultat"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, so there's no why to use regex, and still get the 0000, 0101, 0202 etc?

Comment: There is, but that was treated in some of the other answers. I wanted to focus on efficiency. Regex forces you to use strings, and the conversion + regex execution are costly in terms of execution time. I just added another version of the code that just steps up 101 at a time. No more need to match anything.